# Search code not executing during pagination

Tags: php, filter, pagination

I understand why the below code doesn't execute during pagination as I use `isset($POST_)` but I really don't know how to fix it so I hope you will point me in the right direction.

The code below gets activated when I click on search:

```
$where_clouse='';

if(isset($_POST['todo']) && $_POST['todo']=='search')
{
    if($_POST['admin_rating']!=0){
        $where_clouse.=' AND P.`admin_rating`='.$_POST['admin_rating'];
    }
}
```

This is what enables the pagination and pulls all the data from the table and present it in an array, and that is at the same time the code that gets executed when clicking on the next page, or page 2 etc.

```
$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
$limit = 10; // number of rows in page
$offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `wp_writer` as P WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `wp_writer` as A WHERE `status` = '1')".$where_clouse );
$num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );

$sql="SELECT P.`user_id`, P.`photo`,P.`status`,P.`admin_rating`,P.`my_rate`,P.`country`,P.`skills`,P.`interests`,P.`introduction` FROM `wp_writer` AS P
    WHERE P.`status` = '1' ". $where_clouse ."  ORDER BY P.`user_id`  ASC LIMIT $offset, $limit";

$writers=$wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

Here the search filter code as well to set the todo status:

```
                <form action="" method="post" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="todo" id="todo"  value="search" />
                    <div class="row lefts">
                        <label>Writers</label>
                        <span class="All lefts"><a href="">All</a></span>
                        <label>Levels</label>
                        <select name="admin_rating" id="admin_rating">
                            <option value="0">All</option>
                            <?php $category=getWriterRatings(); foreach($category as $cat){ ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>"   <?php if(isset($_POST['admin_rating']) && $_POST['admin_rating']==$cat['id'] ) { echo 'selected="selected"';  } ?>  ><?php echo $cat['cname'] ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>                                
                        </select>
                        <input class="submit_search" type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Search"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And below the pagination code on the page:

```
                <ul>
                    <span class="go">Go to page: </span>
                    <?php
                        $page_links = paginate_links( array(
                            'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
                            'format' => '',
                            'prev_text' => __( '&laquo;', 'text-domain' ),
                            'next_text' => __( '&raquo;', 'text-domain' ),
                            'total' => $num_of_pages,
                            'current' => $pagenum
                        ) );

                        if ( $page_links ) {
                            echo '<li class="tablenav"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
```

So when I select a level all the code in the header gets executed and it works 100% okay, so all the code is working.

But as soon as I click on page 2 or page 3 all ten results show, eg the pagination works fine but the search filter gets lost in the process cause I can only imagine that it doesn't save the `$where_clouse` part on a page reset.

For example I have 40 rows in the database and when I click on page two the rows 11-20 show, but without the search filter applied.

The solution could be to add the search parameter to the pagination section but how.

I had to fire my programmer as I do know a tiny bit about PHP and they delivered a platform that contains bugs and refused to fix it without me paying again and again. Their typical response: 'we'll fix it when you need new functionality' so at some point I had enough of them, especially after I found out that they are not honest, I asked for a small change which they said would take a few more hours of programming but soon I found out it was only a matter of changing a 0 to a 1 in the code to let messages go through in an unmoderated way, that was the drip that made the bucket overflood (Is that even a saying in English? I know it is in Dutch).

Thank you and a merry christmas!

Comment: Is there any reason why you must use POST instead of GET for the search? Search is usually idempotent, so it's great (and recommended) using GET for it, that should also solve your issue. (assuming there's no specific reason for using POST in a search query)

Comment: No specific reason, I tried to replace all instances with GET and that leads to undefined index errors :S

Comment: When I use form method=get it adds data to my URL like this: ?todo=search&admin_rating=4, and still keeps throwing undefined index errors, while clearly it is defined otherwise that 4 wouldn't show there, I keep on trying...

Comment: Ha, problem fixed :) When I changed some POST to GET I forgot to change the form method to GET, and later on vice versa lol. The URL's just look very ugly now but at least it works. Is there a cleaner way then like this: ?todo=search&admin_rating=3&pagenum=3 ?

Comment: Using $_GET instead of $_POST throws an error? Since you're checking whether the index is set, that seems a bit odd, is there any specific line where that happens?

Comment: Great that it works now, I think the URL looks better that way (the same way that google and facebook does it), because now it you can easily share that URL. You can copy a search + page and send it to a friend, and he'll open in the exact same place.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks a lot Alex!